# Audio Spectrum or Volume analyzer based on PixiJS sound

Tags: javascript, nativescript, web-audio-api, pixi.js

Question to PixiJS Sound API users. https://pixijs.io/pixi-sound/docs/index.html 
How to get Web Audio live dataArray to draw or create visualization in PixiJS without extra coding inline with this spec - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Visualizations_with_Web_Audio_API - I would like to use sound volume and frequency data to modify in PixiJS behaviour of iOS game.

What I am doing:

```
// 1 - loading sound via PIXI.sound.Sound
    const sounds = {} 
    PIXI.sound.Sound.from('music.mp3');

// 2 - sound is playing, I set looping and volume
    sounds.music.play({ loop: true, singleInstance: true}); 
    sounds.music.volume = 0.05; 

// 3 - I reference to Web Audio Context AnalyserNode
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode

    const analyser = sounds.music.context.analyser
    analyser.fftSize = 2048;
    var bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
    var dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);
    analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(dataArray);

// ad hoc temporarary loop but it could be inside ticker

   setInterval(function() {console.log(dataArray)}, 1000)
```

Comment: I don't think it works with native audio, you might want to try a WebView if you still want to use the library.

Comment: Pixi-Sound library (which is not by default part of Pixi in itself) it is using WebApi API. I am loading this way sounds and they expose AnalyserNode - FFT- frequency data - it should be possible to easily get this array.

Comment: actually it works when referencing to analyser is inside Pixi ticker loop.